# Material UI - cannot center content vertically

Tags: material-ui

I can center a content horizontally (left-right) by doing `justifyContent: 'center'` on the parent element. However, doing `alignItems: 'center'` does absolutely nothing, The content is still sticking to the top, when it should be in the center of the screen.

```
const DisplayQuiz = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Box className={classes.main}>
      <Box>a</Box>
      <Box>a</Box>
      <Box>a</Box>
      <Box>a</Box>
    </Box>
  )
}

main: {
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
},
```

Comment: try giving height to the  parent element

Comment: Tried, no luck. My solution right now is just giving it a marginTop. But I am sure there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

Your content are already centered. They are centered inside their parent that is the outer box.
The outer box has no height attribute, so it will occupy height space just enough to cover it's content.
Thus, Your flex container needs to have height attribute:

```
const DisplayQuiz = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Box className={classes.main}>
      <Box>a</Box>
      <Box>a</Box>
      <Box>a</Box>
      <Box>a</Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

main: {
  height: '100vh',
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
},
```